# How to parse a nested column in a df column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, parsing, nested

Is there a smart pythonic way to parse a nested column in a pandas dataframe like this one to 3 different columns? So for example the column could look like this:

```
col1
[{'name': 'amount', 'value': 1}, {'name': 'frequency', 'value': 2}, {'name': 'freq_unit', 'value': 'month'}]
[{'name': 'amount', 'value': 3}, {'name': 'frequency', 'value': 1}, {'name': 'freq_unit', 'value': 'month'}]
```

And the expected result should be these 3 columns:

```
amount  frequency   freq_unit
1       2           month
3       1           month
```

That's just level 1. I have the level 2: What if the elements in the list still have the same names (amount, frequency and freq_unit) but the order could change? Could the code in the answer deal with this?

```
col1
[{'name': 'amount', 'value': 1}, {'name': 'frequency', 'value': 2}, {'name': 'freq_unit', 'value': 'month'}]
[{'name': 'amount', 'value': 3}, {'name': 'freq_unit', 'value': 'month'}, {'name': 'frequency', 'value': 1}]
```

Code for reproduce the data. Really look forward to see how the community would solve this. Thank you

```
data = {'col1':[[{'name': 'amount', 'value': 1}, {'name': 'frequency', 'value': 2}, {'name': 'freq_unit', 'value': 'month'}],
                [{'name': 'amount', 'value': 3}, {'name': 'frequency', 'value': 1}, {'name': 'freq_unit', 'value': 'month'}]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), and [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) could help out here:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

phase1 = [[(data["name"], data["value"]) 
           for data in entry] 
           for entry in df.col1
          ]

phase1 = chain.from_iterable(phase1)

for key, value in phase1:
    data[key].append(value)

pd.DataFrame(data)

 
    amount  frequency   freq_unit
0      1       2        month
1      3       1        month
```

The above is verbose: @piRSquared's comment is much simpler, with a list comprehension:

```
pd.DataFrame([{x["name"]: x["value"] for x in lst} for lst in df.col1])
```

Another idea, but very unnecessary, is to use a list comprehension, combined with Pandas' string methods:

```
outcome = [(df.col1.str[num].str["value"]
              .rename(df.col1.str[num].str["name"][0])
            )
           for num in range(df.col1.str.len()[0])
           ]

pd.concat(outcome, axis = 'columns')
```

@piRsquared's solution is the simplest, in my opinion.

Comment: you can pass a list of dictionaries to the `DataFrame` constructor and Pandas will parse the keys as column names.  This will work as well `pd.DataFrame([{x['name']: x['value'] for x in lst} for lst in df.col1])`

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared; added it to the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that will parse each cell in your `Series` and return a properly formatted `Series` and use apply to tuck the iteration away:

```
>>> def custom_parser(record):
...     clean_record = {rec["name"]: rec["value"] for rec in record}
...     return pd.Series(clean_record)

>>> df["col1"].apply(custom_parser)
   amount  frequency freq_unit
0       1          2     month
1       3          1     month
```

Comment: I think apply will have lower performance as list/dict comprehension. Thanks for the answer though